# Fine Uploader thumbnail creation with image padding?

Tags: fine-uploader

I currently have Fine Uploader creating two different sizes of thumbnails for an uploaded image, those thumbnails are used to show the user a preview of the uploaded image (obviously).

The problem I am bumping into is that the width and height of the thumbnails are variable.  Yes the created thumbnails are within the maximum size specified, but I am wondering if there is a way to ensure that the thumbnails get created a guaranteed size.  This would mean that the thumbnails would most likely have borders of some kind either on the top and bottom, or left and right.  Letterbox if you will.  This would ensure that other components that use the thumbnails do not stretch them, which is what is happening right now.

If that is possible, how would I go about doing it?

Comment: Just a guess, but could you set the `min/max-width` and/or `min/max-height` of the image element(s)? Do you want the "letterboxed" images uploaded too? (We should create Fine ImageScaler :P)

Comment: I am uploading the original image and (preferably) two letter-boxed thumbnails.  Additionally, I also noticed that the thumbnails created by Fine Uploader were not of the highest-quality, meaning the reduction of the original image resulted in thumbnails in which the details were jaggy.  It takes more processing power to create anti-aliased image reductions, but if it were an option, I would turn it on.  I am assuming the FU 'quality' option has to do with the JPEG compression, perhaps not?  As for the letter-boxing, the display can deal with this also, but nice if FU could do it.

Comment: If FU cannot do anything additional to the thumbnails before they are uploaded, is there a way of allowing for custom processing of the thumbnails via some type of callback?  Or a way to use the same image processing lib that FU is using to do additional processing, or even to set some of the options that may be available for the lib.  And if you guys did create a Fine ImageScaler, I certainly wouldn't laugh, I would use it. :)

Comment: Fine Uploader isn't using an image processing lib, it is using the native capability of the browser to scale the images.  Please have a close look at the scaling feature page, where I explain how all of this works, how you can adjust the image quality & type, how you can generate specific scaled versions on demand, etc: http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/scaling.html.  There are options and an API method that address this.

Comment: I have re-read the image scaling documentation, but unfortunately I did not find any thing there that might suggest how to better control the thumbnail sizes other than the maximum width/height.  The image quality refers to the JPEG compression level, not the quality of the image reduction.  I was under the belief that FU was using an image processing lib due to this SO article: http://goo.gl/h71n7W and the inclusion of the MegaPixImageModule library, but upon reviewing that library see that it is specific to iOS.

Comment: On the 'Generate and Upload Scaled Images' documentation page, under the 'Supported File Types' section, the third sentence does not completely make sense, I am assuming it is a typo.

Comment: Image scaling is handled by `HTMLCanvasElement`.  MegaPixImage is used to overcome subsampling that occurs in iOS.  I'll fix the section in the documentation you referred to.

Comment: The typo in our docs has been fixed.  Thanks for reporting this.